# How to show positivity of Fresnel C integral?

Tags: analysis, special-functions, fresnel-integrals

The Fresnel $C$-integral is defined as follows.
$$C(x) = \int_0^x \cos(t^2) \, dt $$
From the plot [found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) on Wikipedia it seems to be non-negative for all $x \geq 0$ however it is not obvious to me why this is. For example, if you make the change of variables $t = u^\frac{1}{2}$ then you find
$$C(x) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{x^2} u^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cos(u) \, du$$
My first thought was to split it into positive and negative regions and make a crude bound. For example, $\cos(u)$ will be positive on $[0,\pi/2]$ and negative on $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$. A crude lower bound on the first region would be $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(u) \, du$ and on the second region would be $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\frac{3\pi}{2} \cos(u) \, du$. However adding these two bounds together yields something negative and so it doesn't work (however, this approach does work to show the non-negativity of the Fresnel $S$-integral).

Comment: For sufficiently large $x$, the integral has to be close to $\sqrt{2\pi}/4$. So it certainly cannot change signs after some point.

Comment: But you actually just need to show that $\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}  \cos(t^2)  \ dt > -\int_{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}^{ \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi }} \cos(t^2) \ dt$

Comment: @DionelJaime Yes, if you could show that the claim would follow.

Comment: A mean value theorem approach may work. But I am too lazy to try

Answer (score 2):

As DionelJamie states, the claim is true so long as you can show $\int_0^\frac{3\pi}{2} u^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cos(u) \,du \geq 0$. I will take this as obvious.

To show this let us split up the integral $J = \int_0^\frac{3\pi}{2} u^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cos(u) \,du$ into four regions. $J=J_1 + J_2 + J_3 + J_4$.
\begin{align}
J_1&= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} u^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cos(u) \,du \geq \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} u^{-\frac{1}{2}} \,du = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
J_2&= \int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2} u^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cos(u) \,du \geq \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(u) \,du  =  \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
J_3&= \int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\pi u^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cos(u) \,du \geq \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\pi \cos(u) \,du = -\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
J_4&= \int_\pi^\frac{3\pi}{2} u^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cos(u) \,du \geq \pi^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_\pi^\frac{3\pi}{2} \cos(u) \,du = - \pi^{-\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}
Adding up these bounds we find that $J \geq \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}- \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left( \pi - 2 \sqrt{2} \right)$. Numerically one finds that $\pi - 2 \sqrt{2} > 0$ though I haven't tried to think of a proof of this.

Comment: For the last part, the perimeter of a regular hexagon inscribed in the unit circle is $6$ so $2\pi \gt 6$ so $\pi \gt 3$. Since $9 \gt 8$ you have $\pi \gt 3 \gt 2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: By the way, is it obvious that the lowest local minimum is the first?

Comment: The first local minimum will occur at $x^2 = \frac{3\pi}{2}$, all subsequent local minima occur at $x^2 = 2\pi n +\frac{3\pi}{2}$ for $n \geq 1$ an integer. Each local minimum is higher than the one that came before it because $\int_{2\pi n +\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi (n+1) +\frac{3\pi}{2}} u^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cos(u) \, du > 0$ by the "crude bound" I mentioned in the OP.